# paper scissors rock python game

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my attempt to create paper, rock and scissors game
There seems to be an error with while loop, "roundNum is not defined", please help?

```
import random
options = ['rock','paper','scissors']

def game(rounds):
  roundNum = 1
  playerScore = 0
  computerScore = 0

while roundNum <= rounds:
  print('Round Number '+ str(roundNum))
  Player = input('Please choose rock, paper or scissors')
  computer =  options[random.randint(0,2)]
  print(computer)
```

**How do I create code to ask the payer if he wants to play again? and if so to run the code again?**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your indentation is correct.

```
import random
options = ['rock','paper','scissors']

def game(rounds):
  roundNum = 1
  playerScore = 0
  computerScore = 0

  while roundNum <= rounds:
      print('Round Number '+ str(roundNum))
      Player = input('Please choose rock, paper or scissors')
      computer =  options[random.randint(0,2)]
      print(computer)
```

Comment: There is an indentation

Comment: @ziGi is that your entire code for the game?

Comment: @ziGi If the while loop is supposed to be part of the game, then the indentation you used (which is indeed there) is incorrect.

Comment: if player == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors' or player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock' or player == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
    print('Player Wins')
    roundNum += 1
    player += 1
  elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors' or player == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock' or player == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
    print('Computer Wins')
    roundNum += 1
    computer += 1

Comment: elif player == 'paper' and computer == 'paper' or player == 'scissors' and computer == 'scissors' or player == 'rock' and computer == 'rock':
    print('Tie')
    roundNum += 1

if player > computer:
  print('Player wins')
elif player < computer:
  print('Computer wins')
elif player == computer:
  print('A tie')

Comment: game(3)     -  that is the rest of the code

Comment: Please update your original question with propper code formatting. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the indentation of while loop.

As function game and while are at same level any object declared inside the game function will be out of scope/unreachable for while loop.

A simple tab will resolve the issue in this case as follow :

```
import random
options = ['rock','paper','scissors']

def game(rounds):
    roundNum = 1
    playerScore = 0
    computerScore = 0

    while roundNum <= rounds:
      print('Round Number '+ str(roundNum))
      Player = input('Please choose rock, paper or scissors')
      computer =  options[random.randint(0,2)]
      print(computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error `RoundNum is not defined` is because you are defining variables inside of a function, this means that you will have to call the function `game()` to define the three variables `roundNum`, `playerScore` and `computerScore`. To solve this, we remove the `game()` function and define the three variables in the main script like this:

```
import random

options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

roundNum = 1 # Defines the roundNum variable
playerScore = 0
computerScore = 0

def game(rounds):
    while roundNum <= rounds:
        print('Round Number ' + str(roundNum)
        Option = input('Please choose rock, paper, or scissors > ')
        Computer = options[random.randint(0, 2)] 
    # After all the rounds are finished, ask if the player wants to play again
    x = input("Do you want to play again? ") 
    # If they say yes, start a new round of Rock, paper, Scissors
    if x.lower() == "yes":
        game(1)
    # If they don't want to play then exit the program
    if x.lower() == "no":
        print("Bye")        
        exit()

game(1)
```

**Edit: if you want to ask whether the player wants to play again, just call the input function inside a variable, then check what the player said, if they say yes then start a new game of Rock, Paper Scissors, if they don't then exit the program**

Comment: Thank you. How do I create code to ask the payer if he wants to play again? and if so to run the code again

Comment: @ziGi you could use an input method inside a variable asking if they do or do not want to play after the while loop has finished, you could look at the updated answer for more info